# Why is a semicolon expected in my SQL statement for inserting into two tables?

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm trying to insert two sets of data into my database and it gives me an error saying that it is missing a semicolon at the end of the SQL statement.

Here is the code I've typed in:

```
procedure TForm9.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
sNewTeam, sNewCountry : string;
begin
      sNewTeam := InputBox('NEW','Insert The Name Of The New Team','',);
      sNewCountry := InputBox ('NEW','Insert The New Country','');

   qryAdmin.Active := false;
   qryAdmin.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Teams(Teams) VALUES("'+sNewTeam+'")' + 'Country(Teams) VALUES("'+sNewCountry+'")';
   qryAdmin.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Comment: Your Caps Lock is broken. Or do you mean to SHOUT?

Comment: Please don't shout. Also, what happens when you put the semi-colon in?

Comment: IMO, this is a basic usage of SQL question, and has nothing to do with Delphi.  i.e. it would have thrown the same error with any database front-end tool such as MS Query, Access, SQL Server, PHPMyAdmin, etc..

Comment: It is an SQL question but let's not make this forum "bounce" or close questions because they're somewhat off-topic to readers who know more than the "asker" of the question.  IMO, far too much of that happens in SO.

Answer (score 6):

Thats **2** inserts into different tables so 2 `INSERT INTO`'s are required.

Assuming your db supports delimiting statements with ; execute:

```
'INSERT INTO Teams(Teams) VALUES("'+sNewTeam+'"); INSERT INTO Country(Teams) VALUES("'+sNewCountry+'")';
```

You also should escape the input text to prevent injection/errors using whatever Paramaterization features are supported by your unnamed database client.

Comment: Ok so i found my issue with the code, the data i'm trying to edit is in one table so i swapped the County(Teams) to Teams(Country) because i'm trying to put the team name and the country in which the team comes from INTO the same table it gives me a error saying that THERE ARE CHARACTERS FOUND AFTER THE END OF THE SQL STATEMENT....

Comment: I dont follow, can you update the original question with details of the table(s) and the query

Comment: Hey Alex K. I appreciate the help a lot, but i am under a deadline, would it be possible to email or send you a copy of the program and if you could please highlight the errors in MS Access and in Delphi...... it would be even more appreciated, Thanks